# Can I use Office 365 University subscription after finishing study?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I am a college student eligible to buy Microsot Office 365 University, a four-year Office subscription. However, if all goes well I'll be done with studying in less than two years. Can I use the Office subscription for the remaining years after that, both legally and in practice?

If yes, can I reactivate the subscription (e.g. due to a computer reinstall) while no longer being eligible?

---

I read through the [terms and conditions](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store?Action=DisplayStudentTermsAndConditionsPage&Env=BASE&Locale=en_GB&SiteID=mseea) and it doesn't talk about eligibility at any time after the purchase. The [EULA](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/microsoft-software-license-agreement-FX103576343.aspx) hardly talks about student software. I also read [this FAQ](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-office-university-suite-online-subscription-FX102918415.aspx#FAQs) and [this longer FAQ](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-frequently-asked-questions-FX102926087.aspx), but both don't answer my question. Multiple Google searches turned up conflicting information.

Answer (score 3):

While writing this question I saw a box in which I could ask a Microsoft Store Salesperson my questions, and here's what she said:

> Yes. You need to be eligible in the moment of the purchase. Once you have purchased you are entitled to the subscription for 4 years.
>
> If you need to reinstall the software, you will be able to do that from your Microsoft Account. It will not verify your eligibility.